# Why is this mantaflow fireball giving bad quality?

Tags: mantaflow

When I render high-res with 450 resolution divisions, the result is completely different from the preview at 64.

I'm using 2000 particles that result in quantized dots of fire, rather than liquid, so I want to blur the particle and have vague swirls of fire like the preview render.

Should I subsample the particle steps or the domain steps?

Why is it so different?

How can I work with previews if the 64 render is completely different to the final render using 450?

hi-res:

[image]
[image]

low res:

[image]

Comment: did u bake it both times?

Comment: Yes it's properly baked just without noise for the moment I'm going to add the shader controls and see if it helps.